# When does globbing happen (here)

Tags: shell, zsh, wildcards

When I pressed enter on this

```
(cd <somewhere>/; ls -gG S09E03*
```

I expected an error from not being a directory with any files matching `S09E03*` (I've verified that), but the command showed information abut the file I wanted information on.

So it would seem my shell (zsh on a patched Debian Buster, i.e. version 5.7.1) didn't do the globbing until it was in the correct directory (i.e. after the `cd`). `cd` is a build-in (it basically has to be), so I guess the shell knew where I wanted it to happen?

Am I totally off? Does it instead have anything to do with the subshell - `(cd <somewhere1>; ls -l <prefix>*; cd <somewhere2>; ls -l <prefix>*)` shows information about two different files, so I don't think so, but I might be wrong (again)? Or is it something else that delays the globbing (respective to what I thought.

- `<somewhere>` is quite long, so I was trying that to avoid getting that path in the output of `ls`
- `ls -gG` because I knew the owner and group of the files would be different between the files I wanted to compare some attributes of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shells (not just zsh) finish *parsing* a command before *expanding* and then *executing* it.

1. Parsing breaks the input down according to the [shell grammar](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Shell-Grammar). This step includes recognizing which characters are word separators, reserved works, command operators, redirection operators, here document markers, quotes, etc.
2. Executing a command evaluates command operators (`;`, `&`, `|`, etc.) and, for a simple command, performs [parameter assignments](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Description-5), [redirections](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Redirection) and [expansions](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Expansion) from left to right.
3. Execution invokes the [external command](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Command-Execution.html#Command-Execution), [builtin](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands) or function if any.

Note that I'm only giving a very general overview here. Some corner cases can be tricky and are shell-dependent, I won't go into those in this post.

When given `(cd subdir/; ls -gG S09E03*)`, the shell first parses it to obtain the following result:

- A subshell running:

  - A sequence of two commands:

    - A simple command consisting of two ordinary words: `cd`, `subdir/` (none with quoted characters).
    - A simple command consisting of three ordinary words: `ls`, `-gG`, `S09E03*` (none with quoted characters).

This is the same work that the shell would do, for example, if it was processing a function definition

```
f () {
    (cd subdir/; ls -gG S09E03*)
}
```

Once it has parsed the command, the shell executes it. It creates a subshell for the subshell construct. Inside the subshell, it first expands then executes the first simple command, then expands then executes the second command. The current directory changes to `subdir/` during the execution of the first simple command. The expansion of `S09E03*`, which is where a globbing step occurs, happens later.

By the way, the subshell is just a detail that doesn't change anything. What matters is that `;` separates two commands, and the first command is executed before the second one.

It's not that “the shell knew where I wanted it to happen” — it's happening where it's happening. The expansion of a command argument always happens in the same directory as the command itself (no part of executing a command can change its current directory, except for the final step which can invoke a builtin to do it or do it inside a function).

Comment: “the shell knew where I wanted it to happen” was a bad way of saying what I meant. It implies way too much. I just meant it as opposed to the directory I was in when pressing enter.